# "Uncoordinated" Maths Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction

[image]

**A single word or number answer is required.**

Hint:

> pi is important, the words multiply and digit may also help :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer is

> Fish

You have to

> take the 17 coordinates columnwise. Each coordinate n is replaced by nth digit of pi. If you link the points the graph shows a fish. [image]

Comment: how did you figure this out ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal The numbers look like coordinates and you have to use Pi. As far as I know yet I was trying out some approaches.